# Gravity Forms get product choices label and value ONLY

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a product field with field ID 7 and i've added choices to it; That's the image below:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGpda.png)

I'm able to pull the selected field like $entry['7'] but the response comes along with the price -> Toyota|30 or Toyota @30

1. How do I get the label only --> Toyota
2. How do i get the value only --> 20000

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for over an hour there doesn't seem to be any way to get this from Gravity Forms directly. You probably don't need this anymore, but maybe it'll save someone else's time.

In my case, I needed some way to get this value and use it for a validation before the entry is submitted, so I used the hook [gform_validation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_validation/)

Your best bet, and what I ended up settling on, is to use the value Gravity Forms returns to find your desired text

```
add_filter('gform_validation', 'price_validation', 10, 2);
function price_validation($validation_result, $context){
    $form = $validation_result['form'];

    foreach ($form['fields'] as $field ){
        //Find our product field.
        if ($field->type == 'product'){
            //Explode useless Gravity Forms string into array.
            $value = explode('|', rgpost("input_{$field->id}"));

            //Get the product choices.
            $choices = $field->choices;
            //Find the key of the chosen option.
            $key = array_search($value[0], array_column($choices, 'value'));
            //Get the text of this option.
            $text = $choices[$key]['text'];

            //Make array with all values obtained.
            $value = array(
                'text' => $text,
                'value' => $value[0],
                'price' => number_format($value[1], 2, ',', ' '),
            );

            //Use $value for whatever you want.
        }
    }

    $validation_result['form'] = $form;
    return $validation_result;
}
```

Or, if you just need the price:

```
$value = rgpost("input_{$field->id}");
if (($pos = strpos($value, "|")) !== false) {
    $price = number_format(substr($value, $pos + 1), 2, ',', ' ');
}
```